# How to use SCSS with Tailwind css?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, frontend, tailwind-css

I am learning Tailwind css.
Could anyone help me with the following?

I want to use SCCSS with Tailwin CSS.

How to achieve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably easier if you share everything you tried so far. including tailwind config file or any other relevant steps. You question is very vague and the docs already cover that https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's pretty much same

1. Install: `npm install sass --save-dev`
2. Import: `import '../scss/yourStyle.scss';`

Your style will be applied.

But I don't think you need SCSS when you use TailwindCSS though. TailwindCSS is very powerful

Comment: Thank you!                                                                                                                                
  Are there any Tailwind pre-built components that comes with button actions like bootstrap

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, there is a library is called TailwindUI but it's not free. If you are looking for pre-built UI components, TailwindCss is not for you. You might want to check other libraries (Chakra UI, MUI, Antd...)

Answer (score 3):

1. `npm install node-sass`
2. Create styles.scss file and import tailwindcss `@import 'tailwindcss/base'; @import 'tailwindcss/components'; @import 'tailwindcss/utilities';`
3. in `tailwind.config.js` add to module.exports next code:

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  mode: 'jit',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  //...
 };
```

Comment: Using sass is preferred way to go, because node-sass is outdated and has some security flaws.