# Not able to use tailwind css classes in an existing angular project which is using scss

Tags: node.js, angular, sass, tailwind-css, scs

I'm trying to use tailwind css classes in an existing angular project which is using scss. I'm new to angular, tailwind and sass so help would be greatly appreciated. I tried these guides but they did not work https://dev.to/seankerwin/angular-8-tailwind-css-guide-3m45
[Tailwind's official documentation to integrate with preprocessors](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors)
[Stack overflow answer on a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76233858)
. Here's what I did

- imported tailwind in styles.scss which is in the root of my project

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

tried importing the default way too

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

- edited tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{html,ts}",
  ],
  important: true,
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

added important: true to override scss styling

- tried to use @angular-builders/custom-webpack. Added it in angular.json and received this error

```
Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ValidationError: Invalid options object. PostCSS Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'plugins'. These properties are valid:
   object { postcssOptions?, execute?, sourceMap?, implementation? }
```

-I'm getting this warning when I re build the app after importing tailwind

```
Nested CSS was detected, but CSS nesting has not been configured correctly.
Please enable a CSS nesting plugin *before* Tailwind in your configuration.
See how here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#nesting
```

I'm using angular@14.

Expected to use tailwind css classes.

Comment: Did you also modify your webpack.config.js to include postcss-loader with tailwindcss plugin as mentioned in the first link you posted? (https://dev.to/seankerwin/angular-8-tailwind-css-guide-3m45)